# iTunes COM interface on OS/X

Tags: macos, com, itunes

Is the iTunes COM interface available on Mac OS/X?  From the documentation I could find, it seems much more extensive than the Applescript interface I could expose through the *Automator* program.

**Disclaimer**: absolute OS/X newbie here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The COM interface is windows-only.

For seeing what Applescript capabilities an application like iTunes has, you probably want to use the low-level *AppleScript Editor* utility, instead of *Automator*. The `Open Dictionary...` menu command in *AppleScript Editor* lets you open any scriptable application and see what objects & commands it supports.

There's also a large library of iTunes AppleScript examples at [Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/info01.php](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/info01.php)