# Can I programmatically add a song to an iTunes library from a 3rd party app?

Tags: itunes

Is there a way to add an mp3 to my iTunes library programmatically from a 3rd party app?

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704262/itunes-com-interface-on-os-x/2704319#2704319

Comment: It would probably be helpful to specify what operating system you're running

Comment: I've modified the title to match the question, since the user seems to be satisfied with non-API answers (and a lot of people reading this question would not be). To answer **does iTunes have an API?** see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689711/itunes-app-store-api

Answer (score 4):

Itunes has a folder in which you can place a file in order to automatically add it to the library.

```
C:\Users\Your Username\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Automatically Add to iTunes\
```

in windows.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [iTunes affiliate resources documentation](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this third party plugin: http://albumbrowser.klarita.net/
Apart from the background monitoring program to be a bit buggy its the best I have found and works well once all setup.